# Zabbix Repport :Cannot connect to web service: timeout was reached

Tags: report, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I'm trying To send reports using the new feature in Zabbix 5.4 using schédules reports. i configure Zabbix and it's sending reports succecfuly but when i open the email i get an email with file not found as shown bellow:

[image]

I have both google-chrome and chromium but still the same.

--UPDATE--
I reinstalled Chromium and but when i hit test I no longer get an email but en error in zabbix with

> Cannot connect to web service: timeout was reached

and when i check this url http://localhost:10053/report
I get the following error :

> {"detail":"Method is not supported."}

If anyone is familiar with this error please help me.

Comment: Same Error here. On which OS do you run the Zabbix Server?

Comment: I believe the problem is with google chrome when I installed it in a VM with no GUI it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image of Frontend URL in the official zabbix document is misleading.

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/install/web_service#zabbix_frontend
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/_media/manual/appendix/install/frontend_url.png

The Frontend URL used in the document is `https://localhost/zabbix`, but if you can use `https://localhost/zabbix.php` to access zabbix pages, you should use `https://localhost` as Frontend URL.

When zabbix web service accesses the web front-end, the actual access is a URL like `https://localhost/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.print&dashboardid=1`.
You can open this URL to see if the dashboard can be displayed normally.

If you use `https://localhost/zabbix` according to the document, and the actual access is `https://localhost/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.print&dashboardid=1`, you will get `File not found .`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. when I changed the URL  worked